# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '[]' to data type int

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, search

I'm trying to create a search function that uses a TextBox and two DropDownLists to return entries from my MSSQL DB. The way I have it set up is by passing the search queries via QueryStrings to a GridView on a separate page. Here's what I have for the search function:

```
Partial Class Includes_LeftCol
  Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

  Public Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    Dim SelectURLRangePrice As String

    If tbxSearch.Text.Length = 0 And ddlRangeName.SelectedValue = "" And ddlPriceRange.SelectedValue = "" Then

      SelectURLRangePrice = "SearchResults.aspx"
      Response.Redirect(SelectURLRangePrice)

    ElseIf tbxSearch.Text.Length = 0 And ddlRangeName.SelectedValue = "" And ddlPriceRange.SelectedValue.Length > 0 Then

      SelectURLRangePrice = "SearchResults.aspx?price=" & ddlPriceRange.Text
      Response.Redirect(SelectURLRangePrice)

    ElseIf tbxSearch.Text.Length = 0 And ddlRangeName.SelectedValue.Length > 0 And ddlPriceRange.SelectedValue.Length > 0 Then

      SelectURLRangePrice = "SearchResults.aspx?range=" & ddlRangeName.Text & "&price=" & ddlPriceRange.Text
      Response.Redirect(SelectURLRangePrice)

    End If

    Dim SelectURLRange As String

    If tbxSearch.Text.Length = 0 And ddlRangeName.SelectedValue.Length = 0 Then

      SelectURLRange = "SearchResults.aspx"
      Response.Redirect(SelectURLRange)

    ElseIf tbxSearch.Text.Length = 0 And ddlRangeName.SelectedValue.Length > 0 Then

      SelectURLRange = "SearchResults.aspx?range=" & ddlRangeName.Text
      Response.Redirect(SelectURLRange)

    End If

    Dim SelectURL As String

    If tbxSearch.Text.Length = 0 Then

      SelectURL = "SearchResults.aspx"
      Response.Redirect(SelectURL)

    ElseIf tbxSearch.Text.Length > 0 Then

      SelectURL = "SearchResults.aspx?search=" & tbxSearch.Text
      Response.Redirect(SelectURL)

    End If

  End Sub

End Class
```

And here's my SQL statement:

```
    SELECT        Product_Rental, Product_ID, Range_Name, Model_Name, Product_Name, Product_Year, Product_Code, Product_Active, Product_DateAdded
    FROM            Products
    WHERE        (Range_Name LIKE '%' + @Range_Name + '%') OR
                             (Model_Name LIKE '%' + @Model_Name + '%') OR
                             (Product_Name LIKE '%' + @Product_Name + '%') OR
                             (Product_Code LIKE '%' + @Product_Code + '%') OR
                             (Product_Year LIKE '%' + @Product_Year + '%') OR
                             (Product_Rental BETWEEN @Product_Rental AND @Product_Rental + 50)
```

Once submitted, I get the following error:

**Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '[e.g. 209.35]' to data type int.**

I'm a beginner at this so apologies if it's something stupid, and I've tried to go as far as I can before posting, but I just can't get past this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type is the Product_Rental field, and what's in it? What type is the variable @Product_Rental, and what's in it? That error message is telling you that the varchar value that's problematic has two square braces and the abbreviation `'e.g.'` in it. It's telling you that everything between those tick marks is in the value it can't convert. Check your inputs. Looks like you've got a "cue" placeholder value as the actual text in the input, and you're submitting that without checking if it's valid.

Comment: The Product_Rental field is VARCHAR and the @Product_Rental variable is a String. The contents of these are prices, so they can have up to 2 decimal places. Sorry, I put the [] in the error message as an example.

Comment: Something doesn't seem to add up as SQL is barking that it is an INT, but regardless, if Product_Rental is prices then I would recommend your SQL DB Type be FLOAT, DECIMAL, or MONEY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Product_Rental BETWEEN @Product_Rental AND @Product_Rental + 50
```

Because you are using `+ 50` [data type precedence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) kicks in. The docs state:

> When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher precedence. If the conversion is not a supported implicit conversion, an error is returned. When both operand expressions have the same data type, the result of the operation has that data type.

So internally SQL Server attempts to convert `@Product_Rental` to an int (because 50 is an int, and an int has a higher precedence than varchar). So whenever This can reproduced fairly simply:

```
DECLARE @Var VARCHAR(6) = '50';
SELECT   *
FROM    (VALUES (1)) T (A)
WHERE   A < @Var + 50;
```

Then checking the execution plan XML we can see the comversion behind the scenes:

```
<ScalarOperator ScalarString="(1)&lt;(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[@Var],0)+(50))">
```

This basically shows that SQL Server has essentially turned

```
A < @Var + 50
```

Into

```
A < CONVERT(INT, @Var) + 50;
```

This is fine if `@Var` converts to an int, but if it has a decimal point it will not, as can be shown by:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(INT, '50.0');
```

I would suggest if your column `Product_Rental` contains decimal data, then it should be of the decimal type, as should any parameters used to filter the column.

Comment: Thank you. That's very informative. I will change the Product_Rental column type as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Type INT is for whole numbers (1,2,3).  FLOAT could support decimals.  And text characters like [ and ] definitely won't work with an INT column.

Edit from Comments:

Since the Product_Rental field is VarChar try changing to this (if you don't want to change the type on the table, which I recommend):

```
--Make @Product_Rental a numeric type first.
 (CAST(Product_Rental AS FLOAT) BETWEEN @Product_Rental AND @Product_Rental + 50)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. OK, that makes sense but I'm not sure where the conversion to INT is attempting to take place. The database column in question is VARCHAR and the SQL parameters I'm using are all String type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
Product_Rental BETWEEN @Product_Rental AND @Product_Rental + 50
```

You've got operands of multiple types there. One of them is an integer. SQL Server is trying to convert everything to an integer, so they can all be compared meaningfully, apples to apples (why does it pick integer? Precedence rules). It can't do that in this case, because in SQL you can't implicitly convert a varchar with a decimal point to an integer. Information will be lost there, so it won't just do that automatically for you. *If* you really wanted all integers, you would have to convert to float, then implicitly truncate the float to an integer. Better would be to convert everything here to a float up front, because you do actually want to be comparing floats here. If you do that, SQL Server won't be left floundering around guessing what data type you want.

So, if the varchar values have decimal points, you will get an error that resembles the one you gave us, but it won't have square brackets in it. (PLEASE don't insert random characters into error messages and tell people that's what SQL Server gave you, if it isn't).

Try this:

```
convert(float,Product_Rental) 
  BETWEEN convert(float,@Product_Rental) 
      AND convert(float,@Product_Rental) + 50
```

This is why you should use the correct data types in your table and in your variables. Both should have been decimal or float all along.

If the actual value in your variable, or in either of those fields, is `'[e.g. 209.35]'`, that can't be converted to float anyhow.

Comment: While your answer is essentially correct in that am invalid conversion occurs, the notion that *"BETWEEN will try to implicitly convert varchar operands to int"* is not, the conversion is nothing to do with the `BETWEEN` operator, it is due to combining different datatypes in the same expression.

Comment: Thank you! Worked a charm. Apologies for the [] in the SQL error.